# How to use Variable groups for a Task Group in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using a variable group to define my proxy variables. As of now I'm linking that variable group to each pipeline I have. But the goal is to use that variable group in reusable task groups as we have 100s of pipelines using a same task group and I don't want to do it manually for each and every pipeline to link that variable group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used vso task.set variable to define the variables mentioned mentioned in Var groups in a inline powershell task which works fine.

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=HTTP_PROXY;]http://yyyy.com:8080"

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=NO_PROXY;].google.com"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, would you please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)